# Can you install Unlocked packages into Professional Edition org?

Tags: unlocked-package, professional-edition, 2gp

We are trying to install an `unlocked` package into a `Professional Edition` org, but its not working.

We are getting the error message:

> **Mismatching Versions**
> The AppExchange Application or component you have selected is not yet available on your instance of salesforce.com. Please check back in a few days to retry the installation. Press the back button of your browser now and bookmark the AppExchange Directory page so that you can find it later.

1. Why is it happening?
2. Is it possible to install an `unlocked` package into a `PE` org?
3. How can we get around it?

Comment: Does this Unlocked Package contains Apex Classes?

Comment: @JefersonChaves - no Apex :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is it happening?

Each instance of Salesforce has to replicate the package. Odds are, it's not yet available in your instance at this time. Try again later. The message suggests waiting a few days, but typically it should be available in hours. If you want to share the ID with me, I'll be happy to spin up a PE org and see if I can replicate the error (you can email me so you don't share the ID publicly).

> Is it possible to install an unlocked package into a PE org?

Assuming there are no dependencies (e.g. Apex code), the package should be installable in that org. You can even technically install a package in a Group Edition if it meets the dependency requirements. I don't see any documentation to the contrary, so I presume at this point it's just a replication issue.

> How can we get around it?

Presumably, waiting long enough should fix it. As I said before, if you want to contact me by email or Twitter, I'll be happy to take this offline with you.